# Repeat region table with minimum number of rows

Tags: php, regions

I have created a table that is dynamically populated from a MySQL database using PHP. The first row is a repeated region for all records. However is it possible to have a minimum number of rows created whether there was a record or not. For example if I have 8  records for a given date could the table be drawn with 12 rows regardless, 4 of them will just be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, good design separates retrieval and data model from display (MVC)

```
$data = array();
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

Now you just do

```
$MIN_VALUE = 12; // Some value
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $row) {
   //Data row
   $i++;
}
while(!$i < $MIN_VALUE) {
   //Blank row
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your response. I've been toying around with something similiar but couldnt get it to work....where in the loop would you create the table row that is repeated? where u have // data row?

Comment: If you want a row repeated after every row, put it in the `foreach`. If you want it before that, put it before the `foreach`. If you want it once per blank row, put it in the `while`

Comment: this is my query..........mysql_select_db($database_#####, $#####);
$query_RsManifest = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE TripinfoID = ###";
$RsManifest = mysql_query($query_RsManifest, $####) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RsManifest = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsManifest);
$totalRows_RsManifest = mysql_num_rows($RsManifest);

Comment: would anybody care to add to this?... i've tried this a 100 different ways and i cannot seem to get any where